# Unable to join the queue

Tags: voip, asterisk

We have an asterisk system which has only 3XXX SIP phones. And we have some queues.
I am using AddQueueMember application to add the agents to queues dynamically as the following

```
AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/5XXX@10.10.X.X)
AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/6XXX@10.10.X.X)
AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/7XXX@10.10.X.X)
```

and after **queue show** command

```
Members:
SIP/5XXX@10.10.X.X(dynamic) (Invalid) has taken no calls yet
SIP/6XXX@10.10.X.X (dynamic) (Invalid) has taken no calls yet
SIP/7XXX@10.10.X.X (dynamic) (Invalid)has taken no calls yet
```

But when i try to add incoming calls to this "queue_name" it says Unable to join the queue.
On the other hand when i add an registered asterisk member to this "queue_name" which has 3XXX phone number as i told you above. It is working and the queue can handle all the incoming calls with rr strategy. And it is valid for all the queues in my systems.

```
AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/5XXX@10.10.X.X)
AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/6XXX@10.10.X.X)
AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/7XXX@10.10.X.X)
AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/3XXX)
```

and again after **queue show** command

```
Members:

SIP/5XXX@10.10.X.X(dynamic) (Invalid) has taken no calls yet
SIP/6XXX@10.10.X.X (dynamic) (Invalid) has taken no calls yet
SIP/7XXX@10.10.X.X (dynamic) (Invalid) has taken no calls yet
SIP/3489 (dynamic) (Not in use) has taken no calls yet
```

So is there a way for queues to handle incoming calls without adding this 3XXX phones? Can you show me a better solution for that?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add them as SIP peers in `/etc/sip.conf`, for example:

```
[5001]
disallow=all
host=10.10.X.X
type=friend
dtmfmode=rfc2833
allow=alaw
qualify=yes
canreinvite=yes
insecure=port
context=somecontext
```

and then do `AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/5001)`. It all depends on your configuration.
If `10.10.X.X` is your dial out trunk registered in sip.conf where 5XXX extensions are registered, then `AddQueueMember(queue_name,SIP/YourDialOutTrunk/5XXX)` should work.

Comment: I've made an edit to post, hopefully to catch your right config

Comment: Thank you so much mirkobrankovic. I tried your second way and it is working now.:)

Comment: Hi @mirkobrankovic , today when i tried to do same thing it gives me bad request - 'malformed/missing url' error. Do you have any idea about the reason for that error.

Comment: are peers registering good every minute? are statuses `OK` on `sip show peers`? Can you do a simple dial to those extensions?

Comment: SIP is getting bad address. That message is usual if you would do `Dial(SIP/Server)` without extension and SIP request would be incomplete (`To:` header for this example). Make sure you are doing right `Dial`